# Kali Linux & Windows 7 : Switching Grub to MBR

Tags: windows-7, grub, multi-boot, mbr, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali Linux (i386) alongside Windows 7 (x64). I have prepared suitable free disk space and placed Kali there. The last thing done by installation was to prepare GRUB. whole kali installation process ended with no errors but after installation My Windows 7 was not identified in grub . Unfortunately when I'm booting my now PC it uses GRUB, so that Windows 7 is not recognized (listed in grub).

I tried proceeding the kali installation twice. Always with same results.

In Kali,I can see windows 7 installation drive with its files and folders and boot files.

I want to work in both

Have you got any ideas how to successfully dual boot Windows 7 and kali linux OR add windows 7 to grub OR replace grub with MBR

Answer (score 1):

Before reinstalling the whole operating system you can try to update Grub manually.

Boot your Linux distribution, open a terminal and switch to root.
Take a backup of this file in case something goes wrong `/boot/grub/grub.conf` by doing something like this `cp /boot/grub/grub.conf /root`.

Now edit the `grub.conf` file by adding the following at the bottom:

```
title Windows 7

rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
```

I am assuming that your windows partition is on hd0,0 since it was installed first, but that might not be true so you will have to find this out yourself. At the end you have to update grub with the new configuration by running `update-grub` as root.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: kali linux has grub,not grub2 so it supports sda and windows 7 is installed on sda3.
I applied your given commands with and without changes but same output comes